# Should I uninstall Python 2.7.10?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, anaconda, conda

I have installed Python 2.7.10 version initially. However, I could not install Scipy and PyMc using pip install. Hence, I resorted to installing Anaconda. Now, I find Anaconda environment perfect for my use and I use Spyder IDE and Anaconda command prompt to run my programs.

Now, I want to know, shall I uninstall the Python 2.7.10 which I installed initially [which consumes around 55.7 Mb of my resources]? Or both these are inter-related?

Comment: Which resources do you mean? hdd?

Comment: my suggestion is to use virtual environment while developement. It would be more better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Anaconda Python is independent of the other Python. They shouldn't affect each other. You may want to remove the other one from your PATH to make sure you don't accidentally open it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned they live nicely side by side, but if you need space on hdd, you can safely remove the standalone installation of python.

Also (instead of Anaconda or side by side) you can use http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ for getting compiled binaries of libraries (including scipy and numpy) that don't get installed that easily using `pip install` on windows

Comment: I visited this page earlier and downloaded the files from here. When I attempted installing, it was posting me with an error indicating that, there is no Fortran compiler available and Lapack/Blas resources not found. Then, I attempted downloading Lapack, Blas and Atlas, but not sure how to proceed after that. I tried easy install too. It was of no change.

Comment: Wow. Which lib needs fortran compiler, if you don't mind my asking? pymc?

Comment: Yes, this error was showing when I tried installing it. But got installed in Conda environment easily with no trouble.

Comment: Which version of OS are you using? I've installed those two and lots of other libs from there on WinXP and Win7 both x86 and x64 multiple times - no problems ever.

Comment: I am using Win 8.1. Not sure why. I tried many times. The same error that "the files need a fortran compiler but it is not available and lapack/blas resources not found", every single time on standalone environment of Python.

Comment: https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/INSTALL.html You can see on this page too. They mentioned that we need fortran compiler to install PyMc.

Comment: The intended way to install it is: download the wheel file, then write from the command line: `pip install pymc-2.3.4-cp27-none-win32.whl` for example. And it installed faster than I've written this message

Comment: I will try this today. Thanks a lot. It was of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you can use some lib correctly by python 2.7.10,but others not.
My advise is you should use one environment, or two python environment include python2 and python3. It can reduce you trouble in future.

Comment: Not sure which libraries you mean but scipy and numpy work perfectly well with python 2.7

Comment: Numpy was installed properly. Scipy was not getting installed.

Comment: Never heard of any problems installing scipy using Christopher Grocke's compiled libs. You must be doing something wrong.